# How to create a "detached" worktree (i.e. one that the main repo doesn't "know" about)?

Tags: git

*(Note: This is **NOT** about creating a worktree with a detached HEAD.)*

A typical worktree added with `git worktree add` (whether created with `--detached` or otherwise) has its state maintained in the main repository, including its `HEAD` and `index`. The main repository "knows" about it when you do `git worktree list`.

So the question here is: how do you create a worktree that the main repository **doesn't** "know" about? The worktree should maintain its `HEAD` and `index` inside itself, but refer to the parent repository for referencing commits and the like.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Note that you can cause yourself a bunch of headaches this way; it's probably better to use `git clone --reference`.

Comment: @torek: Repos can be huge and unnecessary to clone. I haven't encountered any headaches - like what kinds of headaches are you imagining?

Comment: Using `--reference` will keep the clone from copying objects. The problems you can get here depend on what you actually do with your added working trees, but in general, there's a huge issue with the (possibly single, shared) index, and there are less-huge but still fairly big issues with shared branch names and garbage collection. Using `--reference` can still leave you with some GC issues but it reduces the chances of problems. I think your method bypasses the single-shared-index problem though.

Comment: @torek: The shared branch names aren't a problem for me, I'm not planning to create branches. GC is something I've disabled regardless so it's also not an issue, but also these are not going to be used remotely so it's not like I'll be using them simultaneously. Thanks though!

Comment: You're probably safe, then, and your method will be a bit faster than `git clone --reference` (which still has to build some databases). Keep the `--reference` option in mind as a backup should Git stop reading `commondir` files (it's never been promised anywhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is actually very simple. The **only** thing you need is a directory containing the following:

- `.git/HEAD`, containing a commit hash (terminated with a newline)
- `.git/commondir`, containing a relative path to the main `.git` directory from this file itself (terminated by a newline)

You can now use `git reset`, `git checkout`, etc. inside this directory, and it will refer to the original repository for the commit graph and all needed objects, but which the original repository won't know about.